# How do I make the Windows 8.1 task bar non-translucent (opaque)?

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

I often run full-screen RDP sessions from one Windows 8.1 system to another. Since the task bar is placed in the same location (the bottom of the screen) in both, and the task bar by default is slightly translucent, this leads to task bar buttons from one system to show through as a sort of task bar "background" on the other.

How do I configure the Windows 8.1 task bar to be fully opaque, avoiding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings Then click Performance -> Settings... Under Visual Effects, select "Adjust for best performance', then click Apply.

this solved my problem... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The translucent taskbar is a function of the Windows Aero theme. Disabling the Aero theme will cancel this effect, making the task bar non-translucent.

To do this:

> Navigate to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings
>
> Then click Performance -> Settings... Under Visual Effects, select
>   "Adjust for best performance', then click Apply.
>
> This will disable all visual effects associated with the old Aero
>   theme.

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/445971/disable-aero-on-windows-8)

Another option is to disable the translucency of the task bar from the registry. You can do this simple:

> a. Press Windows key + R and type regedit and hit enter to open the
>   registry editor.
>
> b. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
>
> c. Add DWORD value, name it as "ColorizationOpaqueBlend" without
>   quotes, and set value data to 0.
>
> d. Restart pc or change theme.

[source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/how-do-i-make-the-taskbar-solid-instead-of/55cb6c77-9860-4cf6-b937-fdc93c8edb75?auth=1)

Comment: @Michael Kjörling - So did You manage to solve the problem? If You have some further questions, feel confident to ask.

Comment: This not working solutions in Classic menu start you got feature to disable transparent effect: https://superuser.com/questions/463754/how-to-disable-taskbar-transparency-in-windows-8-desktop