# How to disable Aero in Windows 8.1

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, themes

My friend has a macOS computer and he wanted me to fix it. As soon as I used it for the first time, I really got hooked to the theme. So, I downloaded a Yosemite transformation pack and there is this option that makes the resize,close, and minimize buttons look like mac's and says "Use Yosemite OSX frame UI (Not available with Aero Running)". I tried to disable the transparent taskbar but it still didn't work.

Computer Info:

- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
- Processor: 1.80Ghz
- Ram: 4GB (3.89 usable)
- Type: 64-bit

Comment: Erm. Microsoft removed Aero in Windows 8...

Comment: But that option is still deativated

Comment: Then it's an issue with your transformation pack.

Comment: I tried to use: Yosemite transfomation pack, MacOS transformation pack 4.0. You have a download link for a better one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Aero on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/445971/disable-aero-on-windows-8)